# error 403 when i post create request to openstack with restapi , how to fix?

Tags: api, rest, openstack

I'm trying to do a post request for creating a server in the openstack using REST API. I tried this code (followed in the Openstack documentation) but it response 403 error code

request for token

```
{ "auth": 
{ "identity": 
    { "methods": ["password"],
    "project": "7646jkkjds876tdsuhi87fd4d2a953ca3f4",
      "password": 
        {"user": 
            {"domain":{"name": "default"},
             "name": "test", 
             "password": "zxcZXC123@"
             } 
        } 
    }
}
```

}

and my Request for creating the Server

```
    {
  "server": {
    "name": "test-vm1",
    "imageRef": "c8d859c9-ce15-4673-a486-5524ba1e41ff",
    "flavorRef": "0",
    "max_count": 1,
    "min_count": 1,
    "networks": [
      {
        "uuid": "01f1888b-1d12-4e6c-9936-d8175e71f311"
      }
    ],
    "security_groups": [
      {
        "name": "default"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This error is shown when you don't send the project scope in the API token. I corrected my JSON like this and it's done.

```
{ "auth": {
"identity": {
  "methods": ["password"],
  "password": {
    "user": {
      "name": "test",
      "domain": { "id": "default" },
      "password": "zxcZXC123"
    }
  }
},
"scope": {
  "project": {
    "name": "test",
    "domain": { "id": "default" }
  }
}
```

}
}